# problema ao fazer update dados php e mostrar

Tags: php

eu tenho uma pagina onde posso fazer acrescentar e ãlterar dados na BD Usando o update.

Agora surgiu-me um problema porque quando eu faço update de uma página as datas todas que eu peço passam de null para 0000-00-00.
e eu utilizando este codigo:

```
if(!empty($exibe["MedicaValidade16"])) {
```

ele vai me mostrar todos os dados por eles terem ficado 0000-00-00
. A forma de contornar isto?

Comment: Não percebi o problema

Comment: Tente reformular sua pergunta e postar os códigos que você utiliza para tentarmos te ajudar. Sua dúvida não ficou clara...

Answer (score 0):

Isso, ao meu ver, está sendo gravado no banco desta mesma forma `0000-00-00` e não null, talvez seu campo da tabela esteja como `not null` por isso gravado nesse formato.

De duas 1, ou você altera sua tabela, se for esse o caso, ou testa o retorno em sua aplicação assim:

```
if(!empty($exibe["MedicaValidade16"]) || $exibe["MedicaValidade16"] != '0000-00-00') {
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: MedicaValidade tem apenas o deafault NULL 
De resto não tem mais nada

Comment: Como estão os registros de MedicaValidade nesta tabela quando não tem data? `null` ou `0000-00-00`?

Comment: aparecem null. Depois de utilizar o update aparece 0000-00-00 ou em branco

Comment: hmm.. E ele este campo está `on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Dessa forma não está a funcionar correctamente. Continua a aparecer as datas 0000-00-00

Comment: Corrigi alterando o || por &&